# How to calculate the matrix representation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to calculate the matrix representation given the following:

Let $P_3(\mathbb{C})$ be a complex vector space of complex polynomiums and let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}, \beta \neq \alpha$. We have $L : P_3(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$ given by
$$
L(p) = \begin{pmatrix} p(\alpha) \\ p(\beta) \end{pmatrix}, \ \text{for p} \in P_3(\mathbb{C})
$$

which I have shown is a linear transformation. Now I have to calculate the matrix representation given by the formula
$$
_\epsilon[L]_v = \begin{pmatrix} [L(v_1)]_\epsilon & [L(v_2)]_\epsilon & [L(v_3)]_\epsilon \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $V = (1,X,X^2)$ is a basis for $P_3(\mathbb{C})$ and $\epsilon = (e_1,e_2)$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$ but I just do not know what to put into the formula. Can you please help in the right direction?

Thanks ..

Comment: I suspect that $P_3(\mathbb C)$ is not just *a* space of complex polynomials, but that, in fact, it is the space of those complex polynomials whose degree is smaller than $3$. Am I right?

Comment: It is of degree 2 or less.

Comment: And exactly *how* is that different from what I wrote?

Comment: Oh I see it is the same, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Since $L(1)=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $L(X)=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\end{bmatrix}$, and $L(X^2)=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha^2\\\beta^2\end{bmatrix}$, the matrix that you're after is$$\begin{bmatrix}1&\alpha&\alpha^2\\1&\beta&\beta^2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1):

(1) Apply $\;L\;$ to each element of $\;V\;$ , (2)  Wite the outcome as a linear combination of$\;\epsilon\;$ (weird symbol for a basis...). (3) Your matrix is the transpose of the coefficients matrix you got above.

For example:

$$T(1)=\binom{1(\alpha)}{1(\beta)}=\binom 11=\color{red}1\cdot\binom10+\color{red}1\binom01$$

and you have that the first **column** in your matrix is $\;\binom{\color{Red}1}{\color{red}1}\;$.

Finish the argument now.

Comment: Linear Algebra is really not one of my strong subjects. I really do not understand how $ begin{pmatrix} 1 (\alpha) \\ 1 (\beta) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$? Do you mind explaining?

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct? So we have
$$
L(1) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 (\alpha) \\ 1 (\beta) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = 1 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + 1 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and 
$$
L(X) = \begin{pmatrix} X (\alpha) \\ X (\beta) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix} = \alpha \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \beta \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
L(X^2) = \begin{pmatrix} X^2 (\alpha) \\ X^2 (\beta) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha^2 \\ \beta^2 \end{pmatrix} = \alpha^2 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \beta^2 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
which gives
$$
_\epsilon[L]_v = \begin{pmatrix} [L(v_1)]_\epsilon & [L(v_2)]_\epsilon & [L(v_3)]_\epsilon \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \alpha & \alpha^2 \\ 1 & \beta & \beta^2 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: This is right .